# Правильное подключение к серверу TcpClient.ConnectAsync

Tags: c#, tcp, async-await

После выполнения метода Client.main выбрасывается исключение ObjectDisposedException (Доступ к ликвидированному объекту невозможен). Метод main предназначен для установления соединения с сервером, планируется использовать подключенный к серверу объект client в методах для отправки и получения данных на стороне клиента. Если я оберну код в блоке try в using, то ошибка исчезнет, но мне нужна возможность использовать данный TcpClient в других методах класса клиента.

Не понятна суть этой ошибки, почему объект TcpClient при выходе из метода main уничтожается, хотя он объявлен как член класса. Также непонятно, почему это исключение пропадает при закрытии сетевого потока и удалении экземпляра TcpClient в конце метода. Буду благодарен, если кто-то ответит на эти вопросы. В конце кода привел метод принятия запроса подключения на стороне сервера (метод Server.Listen).

```
    internal static async void main()
    {
        try
        {
            client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(Form1.frm1.textBox3.Text);
            await client.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, port);
            if (client.Connected)
                Form1.frm1.textBox2.AppendText("Подключение к серверу выполнено" + Environment.NewLine);
            stream = client.GetStream();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Form1.frm1.textBox2.AppendText(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine);
            Disconnect();
        }
    }

   static internal async void Listen()
       server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
       server.Start();
       while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (server.Pending())
                    { 
                        TcpClient client = await server.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                        ClientObjects clientObject = new ClientObjects(client);
                        clientObject.Process();                          
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Form1.frm1.textBox2.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Form1.frm1.textBox2.AppendText(e.Message + Environment.NewLine); }));
                    break;
                }
             }

    static internal void Disconnect()
    {
        if (stream != null)
            stream.Close(); //отключение потока
        if (client != null)
            client.Close(); //отключение клиента
    }
```

UPD: Вынес инициализацию объекта TcpClient из блока try-catch. Ошибка сохранилась. Добавил сюда код метода Disconnect

Comment: Стектрейс ошибки в студию.

Comment: @SerafimProzorov https://pp.userapi.com/c840232/v840232502/5a5a5/5IW9ykpa7xk.jpg

Comment: 1)По скрину не видно disposed именно для клиента вызывается или нет. Вы уверены что для клиента вызывается? 2) Попробуйте код из main в button click перенести.

Comment: У вас двойная ошибка: падает блок catch. Ищите свою ошибку в методе Disconnect.

Comment: @Vasek не знаю как определить точно к чему это исключение относится, блок catch его не ловит. Что интересно, блок try успешно выполняется, а потом выбрасывается исключение. Мне кажется, что так как client больше потом не используется, сборщик мусора просто уничтожает объект. Мне пришла в голову мысль, что нужно в методе main читать приходящие от сервера сообщения, а не в другом методе.

У меня есть рабочая версия этого tcp мессенджера, работающего синхронно. Там после строки с получением сетевого потока клиента идет вызов нового потока, где выполняется чтение сообщений от сервера

Comment: @PavelMayorov инициализацию объекта TcpClient вынес из конструкции try-catch, думаю решило только часть проблемы. До блока catch при выбросе исключения ObjectDisposedException выполнение программы не доходит, то есть метод Disconnect даже не вызывается.

Comment: @Ramil 1) Сюда по вашему скрину исключение происходит где то в момент вызова продолжения автомата async/await - а. 2) По моей практике могу сказать, что ошибка очень похожа на случай когда ваш код уже освободил объект TcpClient. Попробуйте сначала написать код без кэширования объекта TcpClient.

Comment: Еще попробуйте повставлять в код Debug.Write. И посмотрите на результаты. Если не поможет выложите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Без него очень сложно угадать что происходит.

Answer (score 0):

вынести инициализацию `client = new TcpClient(AddressFamily.InterNetwork);` из блока try{} выше, просто первой строкой main()

[описание try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.120%29.aspx)

> **Из блока try следует инициализировать только те переменные, которые в
>   нем объявлены. ... Попытка использовать
>   эту переменную вне блока try... приведет к ошибке
>   компиляции.**

как бы try-catch должен "прибрать за собой" :) видимо client после выхода из блока try{} выполняет Dispose(), т.к. класс TcpClient наследует интерфейс IDisposable... но этот экземпляр является полем другого ещё существующего объекта, его ресурсы освобождать рано (если это и делать, то только "сверху вниз").

Comment: переместил выше, но похоже это решает только часть проблемы, исключение по-прежнему вылезает

Comment: @Ramil ставьте брейкпойнт на начало `try{ }` и проследите выполнение "по шагам" нажатием клавиши **F11** до ошибки -- так много чего может быть, не зачем гадать на кофейной гуще  :)

Comment: я так и делал, у меня блок try успешно выполняется и когда программа выходит из конструкции try-catch выбрасывается исключение ObjectDisposedException, посмотрите комментарии выше, я там описал более подробно про проблему

Comment: @Ramil  посмотрел, но ничего более однозначного тут просто нет (=__=) 
После выноса из `try{}` инициализации `client` он у вас остаётся "работоспособным" и после `main()`-- верно?
По ссылке см. "Исключения в Асинхронных методах" -- исключение ловится **именно** на стыке `try-catch` + `await|async`, а если использовать `using(){}` его нет -- КМК, это из-за асинхронного выполнения/ожидания методов, попробуй вообще без обработчика исключений -- мне кацца и ошибки-то не будет  :)